# executing an object's method from multiple lists using linq

Tags: c#, linq, join

Say I have some classes implementing some interface

```
public class A : I
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // Some implementation
    }
}

public class B : I
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // Some other implementation
    }
}

public interface I
{
    void DoSomething();
}
```

And a list of each class

```
var listA = new List<A>();
var listB = new List<B>();
```

Are there any ways to execute `DoSomething` other than doing a seperate `foreach` for every list? if so, what is the best (best refering to performace & memory usage) way to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach(var item in listA.OfType<I>().Concat(listB.OfType<I>()))
    item.DoSomething();
```

Comment: Thanks. What happens behind the scenes here? does it creates another list containing the first two or uses the same memory?

Comment: @Omribitan the same memory, it saves you memory but the performance is **slightly** worse than creating a new List<>, (that's what I've experienced, note that the difference is very little).

Comment: @Omribitan using `LINQ` is never faster than using tradition loop operating directly on the data structure, however **the difference is very very little indeed**, while `LINQ` can help you save memory, write  readable and concise code.

Answer (score 1):

Have a:

```
var list = new List<I>();
```

and add to it:

```
list.Add(new A());
list.Add(new B());
```

and then:

```
list.ForEach(x=>x.DoSomething());
```

You can do this because `A` and `B` share common interface `I`

Comment: Thanks, but it seems a pretty memory consuming solution since it creates another list contaning the first & second lists. I'd like to avoid that ...

Comment: @Omribitan I suggest you to use common list. Don't create many list, create one with `A`'s and `B`'s

Answer (score 0):

A shorter form on King King's answer

```
listA.Concat(listB.OfType<I>()).ToList().ForEach(a=>a.DoSomething());
```